# Select dropdown item based on value not working

Tags: jquery

So I have this code.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<select id="cboNameSuffix" class="cboNameSuffix" style="width: 200px;">
</select>
```

Which I populate like this

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: "http://localhost:1818/api/?method=get_all_extensions",
    success: function (result) {

        var $select = $('#cboNameSuffix');
        $select.find('option').remove();
        $.each(result, function (key, value) {
            $select.append('<option value=none>None</option>');
            $.each(value, function (index2, sub_record) {
                $select.append('<option value=' + sub_record.ID + '>' + sub_record.Name + '</option>');
            });
        });
    }
});
```

My problem is that every time I try to select an `option`, I can't seem to make it work.

I tried

`$('#cboNameSuffix').val(student.NameSuffix.ID);`
`$('#cboNameSuffix[value='+student.NameSuffix.ID+']').attr('selected', 'true');`
`$('#cboNameSuffix').val(student.NameSuffix.ID).change();`
`$("#cboNameSuffix select").val(student.NameSuffix.ID);`

and every way I found online.

This is how my UI looks for add and edit.

[image]

Comment: Can you explain why are you looping two times ? explore your logic.

Comment: Like what the first loop does and what the second loop ?

Comment: @AkhtarMunir I was looping 2 times because the api I'm using throws something like `name:[{"ID": 1,"Name": "Jr."}]`. I can't get the items if I only do 1 `each`. And it's working fine.

Comment: @AkhtarMunir the first loop enters `name` and the second loop is the one that can actually see the items.

Comment: Okay, i got it, @minaj but do you see any error in console for the second loop ?

Comment: @AkhtarMunir no errors for the 2nd loop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199349/discussion-between-akhtar-munir-and-rminaj).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already found the answer.

As a temporary fix, I needed to add `async: false` to my `ajax` api call so that it waits for the `ajax` to finish populating my drop down list and then execute the next lines of code for selecting the equivalent `option` of the `student.NameSuffix.ID`.

Found the correct answer.

I made my code like the one below and now it works fine.

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: "http://localhost:1818/api/?method=get_all_extensions",
}).done(function (result) {

    var $select = $('#cboNameSuffix');
    $select.find('option').remove();
    $.each(result, function (key, value) {
        $select.append('<option value=none>None</option>');
        $.each(value, function (index2, sub_record) {
            $select.append('<option value=' + sub_record.ID + '>' + sub_record.Name + '</option>');
        });
    });

    if (editMode == true){
        $('#cboNameSuffix option[value="' + student.NameSuffix.ID + '"]').prop("selected", true);
    }
}).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    // If fail
    console.log(textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$("#cboNameSuffix option[value=" + student.NameSuffix.ID+ "]").attr('selected', 'selected');
```

and change your code as,you have given 2 loops.make it to single

```
 $select.empty();
 $select.append('<option>None</option>');
 $.each(result, function (k, item) {
   $select.append('<option value=' + item.ID + '>' + item.Name + '</option>');
 });
```

Comment: Is that any different than the 2nd code I tried? Also it didn't work.

Comment: is those results are appending correctly? `$select.append('<option value='none'>None</option>');` are you getting any console error here?

Comment: yes, I'm able to `append` the `option`s correctly. I'm not getting any error on the console.

Comment: @NijinKoderi referring to your answer it should be `item.ID` and `item.Name`

Comment: Thanks @NijinKoderi. I can't use a single loop only on my case. My data looks like `{
  "name_suffix": [
    {
      "ID": 1,
      "DeletedAt": null,
      "Name": "Jr."
    },
    {
      "ID": 2,
      "DeletedAt": null,
      "Name": "Sr."
    },
    {
      "ID": 3,
      "DeletedAt": null,
      "Name": "II"
    },
    {
      "ID": 4,
      "DeletedAt": null,
      "Name": "III"
    }
  ]
}` and having 2 loops made me able to properly populate my `select`.